# SQL Server : returning the related xml with value, nodes methods

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a the below sample XML schema that I am querying from in SQL Server 2012. I have a table with a XML column. I want to include the snippet of xml when each row is returned.

Below is the existing query and more detailed explanation.

```
<dev:Doc xmlns:dev="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Number="0" SchemaVersion="0.1" Settings="Testing" Title="Ordering">
  <dev:Forms FormId="A1">
    <dev:A1 ItemNumber="1" ItemGuid="{F402C584-555E-4D07-8C35-E88889B9DA44}">
      <dev:Codes>D</dev:Codes>
      <dev:Required>true</dev:Required>
      <dev:Informational>false</dev:Informational>
      <dev:Visitors>
        <dev:Visitor Name="Dev01" Location="STLRF">
          <dev:Divisions>
            <dev:Division Number="1" Name="TFR3" Usage="Monitor">
              <dev:Description>Development Fundamentals</dev:Description>
            </dev:Division>
            <dev:Division Number="2" Name="DEF32" Usage="Monitor">
              <dev:Description>Testing Fundamentals</dev:Description>
            </dev:Division>
            <dev:Division Number="3" Name="DEP13" Usage="None">
              <dev:Description>Guided Fundamentals</dev:Description>
            </dev:Division>
          </dev:Divisions>
        </dev:Visitor>
        <dev:Visitor Name="Dev02" Location="STLRF">
          <dev:Divisions>
            <dev:Division Number="1" Name="TFR3" Usage="Monitor">
              <dev:Description>Development Fundamentals</dev:Description>
            </dev:Division>
            <dev:Division Number="2" Name="DEF32" Usage="Monitor">
              <dev:Description>Testing Fundamentals</dev:Description>
            </dev:Division>
            <dev:Division Number="3" Name="DEP13" Usage="None">
              <dev:Description>Guided Fundamentals</dev:Description>
            </dev:Division>
          </dev:Divisions>
        </dev:Visitor>
        <dev:Visitor Name="Dev03" Location="FGRTY">
          <dev:Divisions>
            <dev:Division Number="1" Name="TFR3" Usage="Monitor">
              <dev:Description>Development Fundamentals</dev:Description>
            </dev:Division>
            <dev:Division Number="2" Name="DEF32" Usage="Monitor">
              <dev:Description>Testing Fundamentals</dev:Description>
            </dev:Division>
            <dev:Division Number="3" Name="DEP13" Usage="None">
              <dev:Description>Guided Fundamentals</dev:Description>
            </dev:Division>
          </dev:Divisions>
        </dev:Visitor>
      </dev:Visitors>
      <dev:Senders>
        <dev:Sender Name="FGY(14A)" />
      </dev:Senders>
    </dev:A1>
  </dev:Forms>
  <dev:Forms FormId="A2">
    <dev:A2 ItemNumber="1" ItemGuid="{3563F33E-B03A-4859-850E-A87D35BD8562}">
      <dev:Codes>C</dev:Codes>
      <dev:Required>true</dev:Required>
      <dev:Informational>false</dev:Informational>
      <dev:Remarks>Support</dev:Remarks>
      <dev:Notes>Ready</dev:Notes>
      <dev:Visitors>
        <dev:Visitor Name="GHFF">
          <dev:Divisions>
            <dev:Division Number="0" Name="Trial" Usage="None">
              <dev:FromLocation>LOPO</dev:FromLocation>
              <dev:ToLocation>RDSS</dev:ToLocation>
              <dev:Description>Rich Filter</dev:Description>
            </dev:Division>
          </dev:Divisions>
        </dev:Visitor>
      </dev:Visitors>
      <dev:Senders>
        <dev:Sender Name="W33R" />
      </dev:Senders>
      <dev:IsReady>true</dev:IsReady>
      <dev:IsCall>false</dev:IsCall>
    </dev:A2>
    <dev:A2 ItemNumber="2" ItemGuid="{CCFB2D5D-A23E-412D-8541-536451873713}">
      <dev:Codes>A</dev:Codes>
      <dev:Required>true</dev:Required>
      <dev:Informational>false</dev:Informational>
      <dev:Remarks>Loader Ready</dev:Remarks>
      <dev:Notes>Ready</dev:Notes>
      <dev:Visitors>
        <dev:Visitor Name="UDT">
          <dev:Divisions>
            <dev:Division Number="0" Name="Trial" Usage="None">
              <dev:FromLocation>TYUJ</dev:FromLocation>
              <dev:ToLocation>DETF</dev:ToLocation>
              <dev:Description>Web Enhance</dev:Description>
            </dev:Division>
          </dev:Divisions>
        </dev:Visitor>
      </dev:Visitors>
      <dev:Senders>
        <dev:Sender Name="RJ4" />
      </dev:Senders>
      <dev:IsReady>true</dev:IsReady>
      <dev:IsCall>false</dev:IsCall>
    </dev:A2>
  </dev:Forms>
</dev:Doc>
```

Sample query

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (Default 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' )
  SELECT 
     a.value('@Number[1]', 'int') as Number
    ,b.value('(@FormId)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') Form
  --,XmlDocument.query('Doc/Forms') as FormXml, 
    ,c.value('@ItemGuid[1]', 'uniqueidentifier') as ItemGuid
    ,c.value('@ItemNumber[1]', 'INT') AS ItemNumber
    ,d.value('(@Name)[1]','nvarchar(50)') As  Visitor
    ,d.value('(@Location)[1]','nvarchar(50)') As Location
    ,e.value('(@Name)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') As Sender        
  FROM
    XmlTable As X
  CROSS APPLY XmlDocument.nodes('Doc') As aa(a)
  CROSS APPLY a.nodes('Forms') As bb(b)
  CROSS APPLY b.nodes('*') As cc(c)
  CROSS APPLY c.nodes('Visitors/Visitor') as dd(d)
  CROSS APPLY c.nodes('Senders/Sender') as ee(e)
```

What I would like to do is include the snippet of xml after the Form column to show the snippet it came from.

I am trying this

```
    XmlDocument.query('Doc/Forms') as FormXml,
```

The above is returning from that element down, I just want to return everything from `<dev:Forms FormId="A1">` to the `</dev:A1>` for each row related to `A1`. So when Form is `A2` I want `A2` - `/A2` <--- everything between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want to get is the XML that is referenced by the `b` "table", no?

Try this line:

```
, b.query('.') as FormXml
```

Does that give you want you're looking for? It should give you the XML of the `<Forms>` node.